# Assign method of python dataframe object failing to add column

Tags: python, pandas

The following code doesn't add the column mean_val to the descripdat data frame

```
descripdat.assign(mean_val= svrdat02.iloc[:,3:32].mean(axis=1))
```

even though the following works:

```
descripdat['mean_val']=svrdat02.iloc[:,3:32].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: Assign it back to the dataframe. `descripdat = descripdat.assign(mean_val= svrdat02.iloc[:,3:32].mean(axis=1))`

Comment: The documentation for `assign` clearly says "Assign new columns to a DataFrame, returning a new object
    (a copy) with the new columns added to the original ones."

Answer (score 0):

Assign returns a copy.

In your second statement you are using =, the assignment operator.

In your first statement, you are not using the assignment operator, thus you never modify the original dataframe.